# Type of an array containing typed objects and/or paired elements of known types

Tags: typescript, tuples, variadic, union-types

I have an array that holds a repeating pattern of values, where each repetition consists of **one or two** array elements of known types.

See the type `Sequence` below, which works for bounded numbers of elements. Is there a way to make it work for any number?

```typescript
type ObjectValue = [{ style: number, text: string }];
type PairValue = [number, string];

type ObjectOrPair = ObjectValue | PairValue;

type Sequence =
    | [...ObjectOrPair]
    | [...ObjectOrPair, ...ObjectOrPair]
 // | [...ObjectOrPair, ...ObjectOrPair, ...ObjectOrPair]
 // | etc.

const foo: Sequence = [
    { style: 1, text: "hello" },
    { style: 2, text: "world" }
];
const bar: Sequence = [
    1, "hello", 2, "world"
];
const baz: Sequence = [
    1, "hello",
    { style: 2, text: "world" }
];

// const quux: Sequence = [
//     1, "it",
//     { style: 2, text: "would" },
//     3, "be",
//     { style: 4, text: "really" },
//     5, "cool",
//     6, "if",
//     7, "this",
//     { style: 8, text: "worked" },
//     9, "too..."
// ];
```

Comment: Don't you just want `ObjectOrPair[]`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought so too at first, but the pairs are not nested.

Comment: Oh! I see. Then: OP, have you considered having that *not* be your data structure?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sadly, this data structure is coming from an external API.

Comment: I think the answer *might* literally be no, I tried out a few things but couldn't get there. Practically I think you'd be best with `(number | string | { style: number, text: string })[]`, as the code for handling it should be dealing with those possibilities.